# How to make one module depend on another module artifact?

Tags: module, dependencies, maven

I have maven multiple-module project.

```
 A: parent.
    B: child1.
    C: child2.
```

B will be packaged to get jar file and then c will use this jar file to compile the code.

In B, if I run `mvn package`, it will create `b.jar` (stays in `B/target/jars` not in `B/target` -for another purpose).

In C, I need to use that `b.jar` to compile the code.

Now, from A, when I run: `mvn package`. First, I am successful to create `b.jar` file for B.

But when it come to C's compilation phase, it looks like C doesn't recognize `b.jar` in the classpath (the compilation gets errors because C's code can not import the class file from B).

My question is: How can I solve this problem?

---------- `Below` are the pom files

```
A: pom.xml
  <groupId>AAA</groupId>
  <artifactId>A</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

   <modules>
   <module>C</module>
   <module>B</module>
   </modules>

B: pom.xml
        <groupId>AAA</groupId>
 <artifactId>B</artifactId>
 <packaging>jar</packaging>
 <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <parent>
  <artifactId>A</artifactId>
  <groupId>AAA</groupId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
 </parent>

C: pom.xml
       <parent>
  <artifactId>A</artifactId>
  <groupId>AAA</groupId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
 </parent>

 <groupId>AAA</groupId>
 <artifactId>C</artifactId>
 <packaging>war</packaging>
 <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

 <dependencies>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>AAA</groupId>
   <artifactId>B</artifactId>
   <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </dependency>
....
```

Comment: Just as a best practice (unrelated to this question), modules B and C should not declare their own groupId and version; they should inherit these from the parent (module A) POM. They still need to declare their own packaging and artifactId though.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Looks like it should work to me.  But you might try `mvn install` instead of `mvn package`.

Comment: Thanks. It is a good idea. But if I go with install then c war file will also be installed. That one is not accepted in my current project. Only jar file is allowed to install

Answer (score 50):

Try `${project.parent.version}`

e.g.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>AAA</groupId>
   <artifactId>B</artifactId>
   <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: This solved my issue. After going through lot of articles, I think this is the correct practice.
Only thing to note is, your module version needs to be in sync with the version of dependent module.

Comment: Just want to notice that `${project.version}` is deprecated now. Use: `${project.parent.version}` in new projects

Comment: Why does this work? Wouldn't this expression evaluate to the same value as what the OP already had (0.0.1-SNAPSHOT) ?

Answer (score 12):

> My question is how I can solve this problem?

Dependency resolution is done through the local repository so the canonical way to "solve" the problem is to run `install` from A so that modules will get installed in the local repository.

Now, regarding the following comment

> But if I go with install then c war file will also be installed. That one is not accepted in my current project".

Sure, I'm not on your project, I don't know all constraints and rules. But if you decide to use  Maven, this is a totally ridiculous policy (seriously, WTF?) and using a `system` scoped dependency is certainly not a good solution (more troubles later guaranteed). If this policy is real, better not use Maven in that case.

Comment: Oh, you are right. If install only copy the artifact to local repository, that is okay to me. I though install will copy the artifact to remote repository (i confused between install and deploy). Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

i have a solution: using the dependency with the scope=system

in C pom.xml

```
           <dependency>
            <groupId>AAA</groupId>
            <artifactId>B</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${basedir}\..\B\target\jars\b.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
```

and in A pom.xml, put module B on the top like this

```
<modules>
       <module>B</module>       
       <module>C</module>
 </modules>
```

Comment: David, I have no idea of what you're doing and why "war is not accepted in your current project" but, not offense, this is definitely not the right way.

Answer (score 1):

Doing mvn install only places the artifact into the local .m2 repository of the machine you're running the command on.  How can that not be acceptable?  I agree with Pascal.  If you building A, there should be no reason that a the war is placed there.

On the other hand, if you're using Maven 2.2.x, take a look at the [maven reactor plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-reactor-plugin/)?  This should help the crazy unacceptable cannot install C.war into your local .m2 repository policy for the current project.

Comment: Oh, you are right. If install only copy the artifact to local repository, that is okay to me. I though install will copy the artifact to remote repository (i confused between install and deploy). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `moduleA` on your machine say at `D:\moduleA` and inside `moduleA` you have created another module say `moduleB` at `D:\moduleA\moduleB` , for you to use `moduleB` inside `moduleA` you create a dependency in the `pom.xml` file of `moduleA` like so:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" ...>
    ...
    <groupId>net.passioncloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>moduleA</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.passioncloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>moduleB</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
     <dependencies>
     ...
```

To compile the project so you can use it, from the module folder (`moduleB`) do:

```
.\mvnw clean install
```

Answer (score -1):

Here are what I did to solve it:

1. From intelij , create new module from existing source.
2. Change the version of dependency B in A.pom same as version of B in B.pom