# List maven external dependencies - excluding submodules in current project

Tags: java, maven, maven-dependency-plugin

I have a maven project that contains two submodules, one depends on there other.

The project has no code but maven is ok with that. If I perform `mvn package` it passes ok and generates (empty) jar files.

However if I do `mvn dependency:list` I get the following error:

```
Failed to execute goal on project foob-two: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.example.foob:foob-two:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find com.example.foob:foob-one:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT in [Repo]
```

It seems like the maven dependency plugin only works after the modules have been uploaded to the local repo.

Strangely if I do the dependency list at the same time as package, ie `mvn package dependency:list`, it works. So it seems that maven has a different dependency resolution mechanism in some contexts.

Can anyone explain the behaviour? Can I run `mvn dependency:list` as a standalone command?

---

Here's the root pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example.foob</groupId>
    <artifactId>foob</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <modules>
        <module>foob-one</module>
        <module>foob-two</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

Here's the first subproject:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.example.foob</groupId>
        <artifactId>foob</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>foob-one</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Here's the second project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.example.foob</groupId>
        <artifactId>foob</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>foob-two</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.example.foob</groupId>
            <artifactId>foob-one</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Maybe a maven bug. Have you tried with a more recent version ?

Answer (score 1):

`mvn dependency:list` can be run on its own. It appears as if your project is failing because of missing dependencies. Try `mvn install` first.

[how to make one module depends on another module artifact in maven multi-modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4150180/how-to-make-one-module-depends-on-another-module-artifact-in-maven-multi-modules)

Comment: I agree - but in my use case I don't want to install the package into the registry. It seems reasonable that if I can build without installing I ought to be able to compile a list of dependencies without installing!

Comment: @Matthew if you don't want to install your dependencies to your mvn repo, you could  comment out `<packaging>jar</packaging` in your child POMs since that is the missing dependency.