# Dependency injection on multi-Maven project with Spring and JavaFX

Tags: spring, maven, javafx, spring-data-jpa

Hi I'm working on a project with the following structure:

Healthcontrol (Maven parent project), with following children Maven modules:

-dbc (Spring JPA database)

-gui (JavaFX project, implemented as shown https://drogago.net/javafxmavenspring-step-by-step/)

-central (Module, supposed to be used for communication between modules), consisting of configs and services

[Project structcure image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1TOxR.png)

The problem is, that we cannot inject anything from central module into GUI, error: No qualifying bean of type 'hc.module.gui.spring.configuration.Config' available. (injecting from dbc into central module is possible).

To make autowiring for dbc-central possible we use @Configuration 's :

- 'config dbc'
- 'config central'

and we tried to do the same for gui:

- 'config gui'

but it doesn't see any bean of used object.

Another problem is that pom.xml of gui don't see:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>hc</groupId>
    <artifactId>central</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

All pom's looks like:
' parent pom '
' dbc pom '
' central pom '
' gui pom '

How can we make it work?

**Pom healthcontrol (parent)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

        <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.2</version>
            <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
        </parent>

        <modules>
            <module>central</module>
            <module>gui</module>
            <module>dbc</module>
        </modules>
        <packaging>pom</packaging>

        <groupId>hc</groupId>
        <artifactId>health_control</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <name>hc</name>

        <properties>
            <maven.compiler.source>15</maven.compiler.source>
            <maven.compiler.target>15</maven.compiler.target>
            <java.version>11</java.version>
        </properties>

        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
                <optional>true</optional>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                <optional>true</optional>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>

        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>
                                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                                <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            </exclude>
                        </excludes>
                        <classifier>exec</classifier>
                        <mainClass>hc.module.gui.viewsControllers.LoginController</mainClass>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>

    </project>
```

**Pom GUI**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <parent>
            <artifactId>health_control</artifactId>
            <groupId>hc</groupId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </parent>
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

        <artifactId>gui</artifactId>

        <properties>
            <maven.compiler.source>15</maven.compiler.source>
            <maven.compiler.target>15</maven.compiler.target>
        </properties>

        <packaging>jar</packaging>

        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
                <version>17.0.0.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>de.jensd</groupId>
                <artifactId>fontawesomefx-fontawesome</artifactId>
                <version>4.7.0-9.1.2</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
                <version>17.0.0.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-web</artifactId>
                <version>17.0.0.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.controlsfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>controlsfx</artifactId>
                <version>11.1.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.dlsc.formsfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>formsfx-core</artifactId>
                <version>11.3.2</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                        <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>hc</groupId>
                <artifactId>central</artifactId>
                <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
                <scope>compile</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>

        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.6.0</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>java</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <mainClass>hc.module.gui.viewsControllers.LoginController</mainClass>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>shade</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <transformers>
                                    <transformer
                                            implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                        <mainClass>hc.module.gui.viewsControllers.LoginController</mainClass>
                                    </transformer>
                                </transformers>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>

    </project>
```

**Pom central**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>health_control</artifactId>
        <groupId>hc</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>central</artifactId>

    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>hc</groupId>
            <artifactId>dbc</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>15</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>15</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

</project>
```

**Central config**

```
package hc.module.central.configuration;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;

@Configuration
@Import(hc.module.dbc.configuration.Config.class)
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "hc.module.central.services.dbc")
public class Config {
}
```

**Gui config**

```
package hc.module.dbc.configuration;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "hc.module.dbc.repo")
@EntityScan(basePackages = "hc.module.dbc.models")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "hc.module.dbc.service")
public class Config {
}
```

**Example of injection into gui**

```
package hc.module.gui.viewsControllers;

import hc.module.gui.configuration.Config;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.controlsfx.control.Notifications;


import java.io.IOException;

@SpringBootApplication
public class LoginController extends Application {
    private ConfigurableApplicationContext springContext;
    private Parent rootNode;

    @Autowired
    Config config;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        stage.setScene(new Scene(rootNode, 500, 400)); //#todo
        stage.setTitle("Health Control Login");
        stage.show();
        config.run();

    }

    public void init() throws Exception {
        springContext = SpringApplication.run(LoginController.class);
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/views/login-view.fxml"));
        fxmlLoader.setControllerFactory(springContext::getBean);
        rootNode = fxmlLoader.load();
    }

    public void stop() throws Exception {
        springContext.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Baeldung have a [trouble-shooting guide](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-nosuchbeandefinitionexception#cause-1) for the error `No Qualifying Bean of Type […] Found for Dependency`.

Comment: Are you running `mvn install`?  See this potential duplicate: [How to make one module depend on another module artifact?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4150180/how-to-make-one-module-depend-on-another-module-artifact)

Comment: Ensure, that, after you run the install, you [reload all maven projects in Idea](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/delegate-build-and-run-actions-to-maven.html#maven_reimport), "To reload all Maven projects, click the Reload All Maven Projects icon on the toolbar, in the Maven tool window."